# Problem with HTTPie installation on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, package, httpie

Terminal during installation indicates such a problem:

```sh
MacBook-Pro:~ synkevych$ brew install httpie
Error: The following formula
  [#<Dependency: "python" []>, #<Options: []>]
cannot be installed as binary package and must be built from source.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, you will need to install Xcode Command Line Tools (so that Python 3 from Homebrew, which HTTPie depends on, can be installed):

> Install the Command Line Tools:
>   `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I do not know how it turned out, earlier it was possible to install without this supplement.  After installation, I also had to delete the folder "2to3": "already exists. You may want to remove it:"  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

Comment: Try running `brew doctor` to see and debug Homebrew problems like these.